# iOS error: No visible @interface for 'GPUImageSmoothToonFilter' declares the selector 'setBlurSize'

Tags: ios, xcode, gpuimage

When attempt to build on Xcode 8.3.2, I get the following errors:

```
            [(GPUImageSmoothToonFilter *)filter setBlurSize:filterSettingsSlider.value];
```

**Error**: No visible @interface for 'GPUImageSmoothToonFilter' declares the selector 'setBlurSize'

[image]

How do I solve that?

---

Another issue (similar to the one above) is this:

```
                tempImage = [lookupFilter imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutput];
```

**Error**: No visible @interface for 'GPUImagelookupFilter' declares the selector 'imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutput'

[image]

How do I solve that as well?

Thank you!

Comment: You're going to need to provide more code that shows how those objects are instantiated. For starters. GPUImageSmoothToonFilter.h does not declare a method `setBlurSize`. It doesn't appear to be the type of object you think it is.

Comment: Jake, maybe that's the problem, setBlurSize is not declared? I do not see it anywhere in .h or .m. It shows only at that code instance. Provided a screenshot too.

Comment: That's what "No visible @interface for '...' declares the selector '...' means. The .h does not include the method you're trying to use. Sometimes it's in the .m, which means it can only be used inside the .m, but it's a private method so you can't use it outside. If you're using a subclass, you can access public methods of the parent classes even though they aren't explicitly declared in the .h. But, it appears in this case, setBlurSize is not a method of the class you're using. Perhaps there's a property on the class you're using that has that method? Where did you find that method?

Comment: @JakeT. it's weird, the setBlurSize in other instances does not throw this error. It's all in the same .m file. It's only in this: caseGPUIMAGE_GAUSSIAN: {} happening. In case GPUIMAGE_ZOOMBLUR:{} does not throw that error, even if the same line of code is used.

Answer (score 1):

It's telling you that because, well, GPUImageSmoothToonFilter doesn't have a `setBlurSize:` method. You can see that [here](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/blob/master/framework/Source/GPUImageSmoothToonFilter.h).

The above code appears to have been copied and pasted (with the addition of your `isPurchased` check) from the FilterShowcase sample application that ships with the framework. My guess is that you copied that from a very old version of the framework, circa 2013 or so, because [this commit](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/commit/165aac0522be13d83f3bea087086f6cf55bfd4a5) in October 2013 renamed the blurSize property in many places.

If you're using a modern version of the framework, and are basing your application on the FilterShowcase example, I recommend looking at the latest version of that example to see what the interfaces are now. You can also look at the interfaces in the code or look at the latest documentation, as well.

Comment: will it be OK with you if I send you that .m for you to check? You are right, I copied / pasted the latest version of the framework, because as I upgraded to Xcode 8.3.2, the old GPUImage framework threw more errors. So I did not change anything in code, but simply copy / pasted the new framework into the source code's directory. If I send the .m, can you check the new interfaces that are compliant with the new framework to eliminate all errors. It seems like a small issue, what do you say?

Comment: @itzo - I'll be honest, I'm not the one getting paid to develop this application, and I don't really have the time to go through all of your code. It's best if you take the time to read through the FilterShowcase sample application and documentation and do this yourself. Given that it won't compile if you do it wrong, that's pretty easy to check.

Comment: I understand. I'll check but if I need anything to clarify can I count on you? Itzo